# Why can't I change the icon on a tkMessagebox.askyesno() on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tkmessagebox

`tkMessageBox.askyesno('Title', 'Message', icon=tkMessageBox.WARNING)` on OS X just gives me the rocket icon.

I know there is some weirdness with OS X and tkMessageBox icons because `tkMessageBox.showerror()` just shows the rocket icon, but `tkMessageBox.showwarning` shows a yellow triangle (with a small rocket in the corner)

Is this is a bug?

Is there some workaround to get a warning triangle and Yes/No buttons without having to resort to making my own message box window from scratch?

Comment: Question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622115 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72537201/566778 for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
tkMessageBox.askretrycancel(title, message, type=tkMessageBox.YESNO)
```

seems to work, but **both buttons presses return `False`, so it's not of any use.**

```
tkMessageBox.showwarning(title, message, type=tkMessageBox.YESNO)
```

**does also work work**, but be aware that it returns `'yes'` or `'no'`, not `True` or `False`. It's the only real option though.

---

I would still be interested if anyone can tell me whether it is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **icon='warning'** instead of *icon=tkMessageBox.WARNING*

I just tried that on Windows. Sorry I don't have OSX to test

Comment: I think this answer would serve better as a comment instead.

Comment: As a new member I'm not able to comment